# Async/Await not waiting

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, ecmascript-next

I'm running into an issue which I don't fully understand. I feel like there are likely concepts which I haven't grasped, code that could be optimized, and possibly a bug thrown in for good measure.

To greatly simplify the overall flow:

1. A request is made to an external API
2. The returned JSON object is parsed and scanned for link references
3. If any link references are found, additional requests are made to populate/replace link references with real JSON data
4. Once all link references have been replaced, the original request is returned and used to build content

Here, is the original request (#1):

```
await Store.get(Constants.Contentful.ENTRY, Contentful[page.file])
```

Store.get is represented by:

```
async get(type, id) {
    return await this._get(type, id);
}
```

Which calls:

```
_get(type, id) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        var data = _json[id] = _json[id] || await this._api(type, id);

        console.log(data)

        if(isAsset(data)) {
            resolve(data);
        } else if(isEntry(data)) {
            await this._scan(data);

            resolve(data);
        } else {
            const error = 'Response is not entry/asset.';

            console.log(error);

            reject(error);
        }
    });
}
```

The API call is:

```
_api(type, id) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Request('http://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/' + Constants.Contentful.SPACE + '/' + (!type || type === Constants.Contentful.ENTRY ? 'entries' : 'assets') + '/' + id + '?access_token=' + Constants.Contentful.PRODUCTION_TOKEN, (error, response, data) => {
            if(error) {
                console.log(error);

                reject(error);
            } else {
                data = JSON.parse(data);

                if(data.sys.type === Constants.Contentful.ERROR) {
                    console.log(data);

                    reject(data);
                } else {
                    resolve(data);
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

When an entry is returned, it is scanned:

```
_scan(data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if(data && data.fields) {
            const keys = Object.keys(data.fields);

            keys.forEach(async (key, i) => {
                var val = data.fields[key];

                if(isLink(val)) {
                    var child = await this._get(val.sys.linkType.toUpperCase(), val.sys.id);

                    this._inject(data.fields, key, undefined, child);
                } else if(isLinkArray(val)) {
                    var children = await* val.map(async (link) => await this._get(link.sys.linkType.toUpperCase(), link.sys.id));

                    children.forEach((child, index) => {
                        this._inject(data.fields, key, index, child);
                    });
                } else {
                    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 0));
                }

                if(i === keys.length - 1) {
                    resolve();
                }
            });
        } else {
            const error = 'Required data is unavailable.';

            console.log(error);

            reject(error);
        }
    });
}
```

If link references are found, additional requests are made and then the resulting JSON is injected into the original JSON in place of the reference:

```
_inject(fields, key, index, data) {
    if(isNaN(index)) {
        fields[key] = data;
    } else {
        fields[key][index] = data;
    }
}
```

Notice, I'm using `async`, `await`, and `Promise`'s I believe in their intended manor. **What ends up happening:** The calls for referenced data (gets resulting of _scan) end up occurring after the original request is returned. This ends up providing incomplete data to the content template.

Additional information concerning my build setup:

- npm@2.14.2
- node@4.0.0
- webpack@1.12.2
- babel@5.8.34
- babel-loader@5.4.0

Comment: Why are you mixing promises and async/await: `return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => { ... }`? Shouldn't it be `async _get(type, id) { ... }` and no promise at all?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I believe the issue is in your `forEach` call in `_scan`. For reference, see this passage in [Taming the asynchronous beast with ES7](http://pouchdb.com/2015/03/05/taming-the-async-beast-with-es7.html):

> However, if you try to use an async function, then you will get a more subtle bug:
>
> ```
> let docs = [{}, {}, {}];
>
> // WARNING: this won't work
> docs.forEach(async function (doc, i) {
>   await db.post(doc);
>   console.log(i);
> });
> console.log('main loop done');
> ```
>
> This will compile, but the problem is that this will print out:
>
> ```
> main loop done
> 0
> 1
> 2
> ```
>
> What's happening is that the main function is exiting early, because the `await` is actually in the sub-function. Furthermore, this will execute each promise *concurrently*, which is not what we intended.
>
> The lesson is: be careful when you have any function inside your async function. The `await` will only pause its parent function, so check that it's doing what you actually think it's doing.

So each iteration of the `forEach` call is running concurrently; they're not executing one at a time. As soon as the one that matches the criteria `i === keys.length - 1` finishes, the promise is resolved and `_scan` returns, even though other async functions called via `forEach` are still executing.

You would need to either change the `forEach` to a `map` to return an array of promises, which you can then `await*` from `_scan` (if you want to execute them all concurrently and then call something when they're all done), or execute them one-at-a-time if you want them to execute in sequence.

---

As a side note, if I'm reading them right, some of your async functions can be simplified a bit; remember that, while `await`ing an `async` function call returns a value, simply calling it returns another promise, and returning a value from an `async` function is the same as returning a promise that resolves to that value in a non-`async` function. So, for example, `_get` can be:

```
async _get(type, id) {
  var data = _json[id] = _json[id] || await this._api(type, id);

  console.log(data)

  if (isAsset(data)) {
    return data;
  } else if (isEntry(data)) {
    await this._scan(data);
    return data;
  } else {
    const error = 'Response is not entry/asset.';
    console.log(error);
    throw error;
  }
}
```

Similarly, `_scan` could be (assuming you want the `forEach` bodies to execute concurrently):

```
async _scan(data) {
  if (data && data.fields) {
    const keys = Object.keys(data.fields);

    const promises = keys.map(async (key, i) => {
      var val = data.fields[key];

      if (isLink(val)) {
        var child = await this._get(val.sys.linkType.toUpperCase(), val.sys.id);

        this._inject(data.fields, key, undefined, child);
      } else if (isLinkArray(val)) {
        var children = await* val.map(async (link) => await this._get(link.sys.linkType.toUpperCase(), link.sys.id));

        children.forEach((child, index) => {
          this._inject(data.fields, key, index, child);
        });
      } else {
        await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 0));
      }
    });

    await* promises;
  } else {
    const error = 'Required data is unavailable.';
    console.log(error);
    throw error;
  }
}
```

Comment: This was greatly helpful. Thank you. Just one small note, you accidentally cut out `var val = data.fields[key];`

Comment: @ArrayKnight Glad it was helpful! Fixed the typo, thanks ^_^

Comment: The most important part for me to get out of this hell was "The lesson is: be careful when you have any function inside your async function. The await will only pause its parent function, so check that it's doing what you actually think it's doing." Thanks! @MichelleTilley