# async / await / forEach function doesn't wait for response

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, async-await

```
async function updateJSON(original_JSON, assets_arr) {
  Object.keys(original_JSON).forEach(key => {original_JSON[key].active = false}); // reset all records
  Object.keys(assets_arr).forEach(async key => {
    let idx = original_JSON.findIndex(x => x.name === assets_arr[key].name);
    if (idx === -1) { // no match -> insert a new record
      const code_nr = await getCode(assets_arr[key].token_id);
      let debug = original_JSON.push({ name: assets_arr[key].name, active: true, code: code_nr });
      console.log("List len now:", debug);
    } else { original_JSON[idx].active = true; } // there is a match, so just update existing record to become 'active'
  });
  return original_JSON;
}

console.table(await updateJSON(original_JSON, assets_arr));
```

I cannot figure out a way for the code to wait for `await getcode` to finish before returning the function. I get a partial execution immediately and only then the code related to `original_JSON.push` is executed one record at the time.

If I remove `async` from line 3 and `await` from line 6 the function is executed sequentially(synchronously?), except then I get "Promise {  }" instead of the code number the `getCode` function is supposed to retrieve. This number comes from a URL `fetch()`.

I did read [Async/Await not waiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34365952/async-await-not-waiting) and I think my problem is related. Do I need to use `map()` instead of `forEach()`? I find `map()` confusing. I do want to mutate the array, I'm not interested in making a new one (although I'll do it if that's what will fix this).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop does help, and also adds an insight on reading in sequence/paralel. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution from [Nodejs forEach function doesn't wait for async functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60404813/nodejs-foreach-function-doesnt-wait-for-async-functions): replacing the `async` `forEach` with a `for` loop fixes the problem. A `while` loop should work too. These fancy loop methods tripping people up when the simple ones do the job better!

```
async function updateJSON(original_JSON, assets_arr) {
  Object.keys(original_JSON).forEach(key => {original_JSON[key].active = false}); // reset all records
  for (const key in assets_arr) {
    let idx = original_JSON.findIndex(x => x.name === assets_arr[key].name);
    if (idx === -1) { // no match -> insert a new record
      const code_nr = await getCode(assets_arr[key].token_id);
      let debug = original_JSON.push({ name: assets_arr[key].name, active: true, code: code_nr });
      console.log("List len now:", debug);
    } else { original_JSON[idx].active = true; } // there is a match, so just update existing record to become 'active'
  };
  return original_JSON;
}

console.table(await updateJSON(original_JSON, assets_arr));
```